# Data structures to throttle/limit 2D physics collision testing to only nearby objects?

Tags: java, game-physics, physics-engine

I have a 2D world with a positive coordinate system. **(0,0) is the top-left of the map** and **every object has positive co-ordinates**.

For example, in the following pixel array, **A is the origin at (0,0)** and **B is an object at (4,3)**.

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
0 A - - - - - - - -
1 - - - - - - - - -
2 - - - - - - - - -
3 - - - - B - - - -
4 - - - - - - - - -
5 - - - - - - - - -
6 - - - - - - - - -
```

Next, **each object has an (x,y) position as well as a width and height**.

The (x,y) position is the top left of the object and it spans a certain width right and height down.

Let's take **B at (4,3) with a width of 3 and a height of 3**. Therefore, B occupies the following space on the map:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
0 A - - - - - - - -
1 - - - - - - - - -
2 - - - - - - - - -
3 - - - - +---+ - -
4 - - - - | B | - -
5 - - - - +---+ - -
6 - - - - - - - - -
```

Next, let's **assume I can clearly determine if two objects collide**.

But there are 5,000 objects. I could easily implement a very naive method such as:

```
for each object o in world:
  for each object j in world:
    if o != j and o.collides(j):
      print: Collision between o and j!
```

However, this is clearly an *O(n^2)* method with a traditional list. If I used a binary search tree or sorted array to store all of the objects, I could reduce this down to *O(nlogn)* because searching BSTs and sorted arrays is a *O(logn)* operation.

**Is this the absolute best I can do?** Is there no better way to do this? Is there a way to maybe reduce the amount of objects B can collide with?

Since B is only 3,3 wide and high, clearly it is confined to only interacting with objects within 3 of its bounds. Could this be the key to limiting the physical objects it might interact with?

*Code is not necessary unless you feel very nice. I'm more interested in theory and what my options are. Any discussion is welcome. Thank you!*

Comment: Take a look at [octrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree): "An octree is a tree data structure in which each internal node has exactly eight children. Octrees are most often used to partition a three-dimensional space by recursively subdividing it into eight octants." *(Disclaimer: I am not a game programmer.)*

Comment: @JohnKugelman Should be quad tree because op uses 2D...

Comment: Right you are. I should have linked to [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).